# Differences in Syntax for list comprehensions

Tags: python

I appreciate this may be a duplicate, but after reviewing a few questions here i am still unable to see the answer.

I'm getting a syntax error from my code using list comprehension. I have a list, a, containing some numbers, and am trying to output a new list, containing only the even numbers.

The code i'm trying to shorten is:

```
b = [] 
for num in a:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        b.append(num)
print(b)
```

What i wrote is:

```
evens = [num if num % 2 == 0 for num in a]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However i get a syntax error at the point above.

I re-wrote the comprehension as:

```
even = [num for num in a if num % 2 ==0]
```

And this worked.

I know from reading the documentation, thee are two ways to write a list comprehension:

```
A for B in C if <condition>
```

and

```
A if <condition> for b in C
```

What is wrong in the first case?

Comment: "I know from reading the documentation, there are **two** ways ..." – source?

Comment: `A if <condition> for b in C` perhaps in the original documentation, it was talking about `if else`. A pure `if` statement, cannot fit there syntax wise. As the error indicates. This statement, with just an `if`, is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For list comprehensions with `if else`:

```
[f(x) if condition else g(x) for x in sequence] # expression1 if condition else expression2 for item in iterable
```

And, for list comprehensions with `if` conditions only:

```
[f(x) for x in sequence if condition] # expression for item in iterable if condition
```

Note that this actually uses a different language construct, a conditional expression, which itself is not part of the comprehension syntax, while the if after the for…in is part of list comprehensions and used to filter elements from the source iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, the "if" statement has to come at the end of the list comprehension if there is no "else". You can write:

```
A if <condition> else D for B in C
```

But you cannot write

```
A if <condition> for B in C
```

because there is no "else".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good catch

Comment: [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions) covers list comprehensions and backs this up.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a some kind of ternary operator. Here is it:

`A if COND else B`

It is used as the whole chunk of code. Also list generators can have an `if`-statement in the end of the body that are used to filter values. So all of these generators are correct:

```
[A for ... in very_long_iterator]
[(A if COND else B) for ... in very_long_iterator]
[(A if COND else B) for ... in very_long_iterator if COND2]
```

*( `()` are not necessary but they are used to differ if-else from generator-if)*

But you can't use `if` before `for` and without `else` because it:

- is not a 'ternary' code chunk
- is not a generator's `if`-statement because it is before `for`

So it raises an error.